# Find children elements filter by type

Tags: pywinauto

I'd like to find children elements in a window but only of a certain type / 
class.

I use that code:

```
def get_visible_buttons(window):
    children = window.Children()
    return [
                child for child in children
                if child.FriendlyClassName() == 'Button'
                and child.is_visible()
           ]
```

Is there a best way to filter children list ?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's coming in pywinauto 0.6.0 (currently in master branch).

```
buttons_only = window.children(control_type='Button')
```

The list of possible control types is to be done.
The list of keyword arguments for `children()` is also not complete yet. See [the code](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/blob/master/pywinauto/base_wrapper.py#L342).

Comment: Notice that the filtering works only for UIA backend. For the native, win32, backend the children and descendants methods just return the whole list.